# Neo4jrb: a way to query for the model_class while doing collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb

Is there a way to have a couple generic lines of code that can return results from the correct `model_class` based on the the model definition, and not on the lines of code?

Right now, I'm using a generator to create:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:semanticZoomOut, Class.all.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name },
  :id, :name, options = {
    :prompt => "Please Select an Item",
    :selected => @instance.semanticZoomOut.map(&:id)
  }, html_options = {:multiple => true, :class=>"search"}) %>
```

Where "Class" has to be manually changed for each `_form.html.erb`.
Preferably, I'd like to generate something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:semanticZoomOut, @instance.semanticZoomOut.class.all.sort { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name },
  :id, :name, options = {
    :prompt => "Please Select an Item",
    :selected => @instance.semanticZoomOut.pluck(id)
  }, 
  html_options = {:multiple => true, :class=>"search"}) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
clazz = @instance.class.associations[:semanticZoomOut].model_class.to_s.constantize
clazz.all.sort_by(&:name)
```

Or if you want to let Cypher do the work:

```
clazz.order(:name)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken. that would give the class of the instance, not it's related node.

Comment: `@instance.class` gives you the class and then calling methods like `all`, `order`, `where`, etc... will give you a scoped representation of nodes for that class.  What do you mean by "related node"?

Comment: What I mean by related node is that if I have a `has_many` relationship on `(instance)-[:SEMANTIC_ZOOM_OUT]->(zoomedOutObject)`, and each has a different class, then what I want is the class of the "related node" `zoomedOutObject`, not the class of `instance`.

Comment: (p.s. Thanks for the tip on sorting)

Comment: Oh, yeah, duh ;)  You can reflect on the associations by calling the `associations` method on a class and each association will have a `model_class` method.  See my updated answer

Comment: That seems to get very close, returning the right Class name, but doing `clazz.all` gets `undefined method 'all' for :ZoomedOutObject:Symbol`

Comment: Ah, right, I thought that would be a class constant.  You'll probably need `to_s.constantize` on the end (just updated the answer)